# SQL Loader - Use Replace and Append in same control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

As mentioned in the title, i wish to have a control file to handle this case. The scenario is i have to insert record into different table. For example, WHEN (1:3) is HEA, it need to Append into table header. WHEN (1:3) is DTL it need replace into table Detail. is that possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a situation where data from one file goes to three tables depending on the first field in the file.  The `WHEN` clause looks at the first field and takes action based on that.  Notice that when a 'WHEN' is met, the first field is then skipped by declaring it a `filler`. To answer your question, I believe you can put the `APPEND` or `REPLACE` after the  `INTO TABLE` clause.  Give it a try and let us know.

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE)
UNRECOVERABLE
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE TABLE_A
WHEN (01) = 'CLM'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( rec_skip     filler POSITION(1)
 ,CLM_CLAIM_ID CHAR NULLIF(CLM_CLAIM_ID=BLANKS)
 ...
)

INTO TABLE TABLE_B
WHEN (01) = 'SLN'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( rec_skip    filler POSITION(1)
 ,SL_CLAIM_ID CHAR NULLIF(SL_CLAIM_ID=BLANKS)
 ...
)

INTO TABLE TABLE_C
WHEN (01) = 'COB'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( rec_skip filler POSITION(1)
 ,COB_CLAIM     
 ...
)
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657

Comment: i had already tried
    REPLACE INTO TABLE A
    (
    bla bla
    )
    REPLACE INTO TABLE B
    (
    bla bla
    )
but its not working in this way

Comment: According to the link, the APPEND or REPLACE should be AFTER the INTO TABLE clause as I mentioned above.  Please try that instead and let us know.